# Run some jQuery when any option group option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you run jQuery when any option group option is selected. In this case I want to make inputs show and hide based on when any option in one of the two option groups is selected.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <optgroup label="One">
        <option value="1">Value 1.1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 1.2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 1.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Two">
        <option value="4">Value 2.1</option>
        <option value="5">Value 2.2</option>
        <option value="6">Value 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<input id="inputOne" type="text" placeholder="Input one"/>
<input id="inputTwo" type="text" placeholder="Input two"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/u76eynap/2/

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <optgroup label="One">
        <option value="1">Value 1.1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 1.2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 1.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Two">
        <option value="4">Value 2.1</option>
        <option value="5">Value 2.2</option>
        <option value="6">Value 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#inputOne, #inputTwo").hide();

$('select').change(function () {
    if ($("select option:selected").parent()[0].label == "One") {
        $("#inputOne").show();
        $("#inputTwo").hide();
    } else if ($("select option:selected").parent()[0].label == "Two") {
        $("#inputTwo").show();
        $("#inputOne").hide();
    } else {
        $("#inputOne, #inputTwo").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :Initially hide input fields. Then get the parent of selected option and read its label. Using that label identify the input and make it visible

HTML:

```
<input id="inputOne" type="text" placeholder="Input one" style="display:none;"/>
<input id="inputTwo" type="text" placeholder="Input two" style="display:none;"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        var $optionGroup = $(this).find('option:selected').closest('optgroup');
        //use jquery start attribute selector to hide all inputs
        $('input[id^=input]').hide();
        //select input respective to selected optgroup and show it.
        $('input[id=input' + $optionGroup.attr('label') + ']').show();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p00z5kes/2/)**